# Blazor EditForm Submission Issue: modeltodoTask Empty on Submit

Tags: asp.net, .net, blazor

I fill in the modeltodoTask objects with Editform and send them to the "AddTask()" function, but when I check the data before adding them, they are all empty.

1-) modeltodoTask.Text= must be the value to be filled in the form.

2-) I want the value "modeltodoTask.StatusId=Status.Id"

My goal is to create a todolist app and save the newly added tasks to the database with the id value of the form they are in.

https://github.com/iamumutcan/ToDoListApp

```
 <EditForm Model="modeltodoTask" OnValidSubmit="AddTask" FormName="@Status.Name">
 <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
 <ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>
 <div class="form-group">
     <label>Görev giriniz</label>
     <InputText @bind-Value="modeltodoTask.Text"></InputText>
     <ValidationMessage For="(()=>modeltodoTask.Text)"></ValidationMessage>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group py-2">
     <button class="btn btn-primary">Ekle</button>
 </div>
```

```
private IEnumerable<TodoStatus> Statuses { get; set; } = new List<TodoStatus>();
private IEnumerable<TodoStatus> OtherStatuses { get; set; } = new List<TodoStatus>();
private IEnumerable<TodoTask> Tasks { get; set; } = new List<TodoTask>();
public TodoTask todoTask = new TodoTask();
private TodoTask modeltodoTask { get; set; } = new TodoTask();

public bool IsLoading { get; set; } = true;
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Statuses = await _statusRepository.GetAllWithTasks();
    OtherStatuses = await _statusRepository.GetAll();
    IsLoading = false;
    modeltodoTask ??= new();
    await Task.CompletedTask;

}

public List<TodoStatus> GetByIdExcludingAsync(int id)
{
    return OtherStatuses.Where(x => x.Id != id).ToList();
}

public async Task AddTask()
{
    await _taskRepository.Create(modeltodoTask);
}
```